# I need to write a regex expression to search by certain set

Tags: regex

Need to write a regex expression that will search for following sets:

mvm5260bdc
mvm5260cdc
mvm7201cdc
mvm7201bdc
mvm2707bdc
mvm2707cdc
mvm3076bdc
mvm3076cdc
mvm4691cdc
mvm4691bdc
mvm7072cdc
mvm7072bdc

I came up with this mvm[2-7][0-7][0-9][0-9][b|c]dc, im able to search these sets using this regex but other sets are also showing up. Is it possible to make it more crisp?

Comment: Looks like you are looking to create a regex, but do not know where to get started. Please check [Reference - What does this regex mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618) resource, it has plenty of hints. Also, refer to [Learning Regular Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736) post for some basic regex info. Once you get some expression ready and still have issues with the solution, please edit the question with the latest details and we'll be glad to help you fix the problem.

Comment: Welcome to SO! If you're having efficiency problems, please show your current regex and profile showing the performance it's currently exhibiting and where you need performance to be. It's hard to determine "best" without a comparative goal. Thanks.

Comment: This site I find useful in constructing REGEX https://regex101.com/

Comment: I came up with this mvm[2-7][0-7][0-9][0-9][b|c]dc, im able to search these sets using this regex but other sets are also showing up. Is it possible to make it more crisp?